# Oбмен данными между приложением и сервисом

Tags: android, архитектура

Правильно ли я понимаю обмен данными между приложением и сервисом?

Сервис получает данные из сети и отправляет их в приложение через sendBroadcast. В свою очередь приложение получает данные через BroadcastReceiver и отображает их на экране.

Насколько является верным описанный мной подход.

Comment: вполне..........

Comment: А зачем вам использовать сервис? Сервис используется в основном для тяжелых задач типа скачивания 1-∞ гб файлов. Если просто REST тогда OkHttp  и вызовы методов с callback-ами и все.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что хоть это и "просто REST", данные идут тяжёлые. Отсюда и потребность в сервисе.